# npm script to rename files with the version specified in package.json

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-scripts

In the script section of my `package.json` file, I'm trying to rename some files in a directory, however I would like to inject a value in the command line that is taken from the `package.json` itself (version).

So in the case below, the `build:rename` script, I would like it to replace a token in the script (**`somevalue`**) before executing it.

In this case I would like to pass in the `npm_package_version` so that it's part of the name of the file.  I'm at a loss...

```json
"scripts": {
    "build:copy": "mkdirp dist && cp src/*.js dist/",
    "build:rename": "renamer --regex --find '(.+)(.js)' --replace '$1**somevalue**$2' dist/*"
}
```

Comment: Let's say your `npm_package_version` is currently `1.2.0` and you have some files copied to the  `dist` directory, namely;  `foo.js`, `baz.js`, and `quux.js`. Should running the `build:rename` script result in the files being renamed to `foo1.2.0.js`, `baz1.2.0.js`, and `quux1.2.0.js` ? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it didn't... the --replace argument takes a quoted string argument and everything I tried failed where I tried to get the script to substitute the value in npm_module_version which is a global value node provided from in the scope of the package.json file.

If you see my example in the original question, the regex is making two groups that I can use in the templating of the output file name, but I need to be able to inject the the version number in that output filename. If needs to evaluate the npm_package_version value rather than accept the variable name as literal.

Comment: Thanks, I understood what your regex is trying to achieve, and what `npm_package_version` is. In my previous comment I was simply providing a hypothetical example of input file names and resultant file names  to clarify exactly what your desired result is. So, within the context of my previous comment, should `baz.js` be renamed to `baz1.2.0.js`?

Comment: Yes, to your question.  I'm trying to use the version number in package.json as the one and only place it's defined but be able to use it any place there needs to be some stamping or identifying a file with a version.  I would rather not have to update the literal part of the --replacement value in the renamer npm script everytime the version changes.

Answer (score 11):

The current `version` specified in `package.json` can be referenced via the script using [package.json vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars) as follows:

---

**bash**

In *bash* shells using the syntax - *(note the dollar `$` prefix)*:

`$npm_package_version`

---

**Windows**

In *cmd.exe* and *Powershell* using the syntax  - *(note the percentage `%` prefix and suffix)*:

`%npm_package_version%`

---

**cross-patform**

To achieve this cross-platform utlize [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var):

`$ npm i -D cross-var`

The `build:rename` script can be revised as follows:

```json
"scripts": {
  ...
  "build:rename": "cross-var \"renamer --regex --find '\\.js$' --replace '$npm_package_version.js' dist/*\""
},
```

*Note*: the additional change to the `--find` regular expression as `cross-var` doesn't seem to play nice when the `--replace` value includes dollar references (`$1`, `$2`) to the parenthesised substrings/groups in the `--find` value. The new regex simply matches the files/strings part ending in `.js` instead.

---

**Example directory**

Running the updated `build:rename` script, (when the `version` in `package.json` is `0.3.0`), will rename the `.js` files in the `dist` directory from this:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── a.html
│   ├── b.css
│   ├── foo.js
│   ├── bar.js
│   └── quux.js
```

...to this:

```
.
├── dist
│   ├── a.html
│   ├── b.css
│   ├── foo0.3.0.js
│   ├── bar0.3.0.js
│   └── quux0.3.0.js
```

**Additional note**

The [cp](https://ss64.com/bash/cp.html) command used in the `build:copy` script will also not work cross-platform. This can be substituted with the [copyfiles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/copyfiles) package:

`$ npm i -D copyfiles`

... and the `build:copy` script then replaced with the following:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build:copy": "copyfiles -u 1 \"src/*.js\" \"dist\"",
   ...
},
```

The `mkdirp dist &&` part in your script then becomes redundant as `copyfiles` with create the necessary directory (i.e. `dist`).

If cross-platform is not necessary for your use-case then simply leave the `build:copy` script as-is, and change your `build:rename` script to:

```json
"build:rename": "renamer --regex --find '\\.js$' --replace $npm_package_version'.js' dist/*"
```